# Select a valid choice. x is not one of the available choices

Tags: python, django, forms

I know this question has been asked a dozen times already on Stackoverflow, but I have been through all of them and they don't fix my problem. Usually most of them are related to choices being characters when the model field is integer and vice versa. But this is my situation

I'm working on Django helpdesk, an open source django based ticketing platform that can be found here: https://github.com/django-helpdesk/django-helpdesk

And I have made a few changes to their forms.py for Public ticket submission and it was working all this while until I recently added a new queue.

Forms.py

```
class PublicTicketForm(CustomFieldMixin, forms.Form):

    queue = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        label=_('Queue'),
        required=True,
        choices=()
    )
```

So, this form will get choices populated in the views when its called

```
form = PublicTicketForm(initial=initial_data)
        form.fields['queue'].choices = [(q.id, q.title) for q in Queue.objects.filter(allow_public_submission=True)] + \
                                       [('', 'Other')] #I'm thinking this line may be the problem here


    return render(request, 'helpdesk/public_homepage.html', {
        'form': form,
        'helpdesk_settings': helpdesk_settings,
    })
```

Here's what the `form.fields['queue'].choices` prints:

> [(6L, u'Account'), (7L, u'Support'), (4L, u'Orders'), (5L,
>   u'Products'), (8L, u'Request '), (u'', u'Other')]

So, whenever I select a queue and submit, the form won't submit and will throw me this error.

```
"Not one of the available choices"
```

As far I can see, the choices are all integers and not characters. What am I missing here? All help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are the ids printing as `6L`, `7L` etc?  What does the `L` mean?  What type is `Queue.id`?

Comment: I think L means long integer type. When I do a `type(q.id)`, it says `Long`

Comment: Is there some particular reason that you're using Python 2? FWIW, in Python 3, `int` and `long` have been unified into an improved `int` type.

Comment: No reason actually, we haven't had time to move to Python3

Comment: Please show the entire view.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are setting the choices for GET requests, but not for POST requests when the form data is validated. You could avoid this issue by moving the code that sets the choices into the form's `__init__` method. itself.

```
class PublicTicketForm(CustomFieldMixin, forms.Form):

    queue = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        label=_('Queue'),
        required=True,
        choices=()
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PublicTicketForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['queue'].choices = [(q.id, q.title) for q in Queue.objects.filter(allow_public_submission=True)] + [('', 'Other')]
```

Note that it might be simpler to use a [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield):

```
class PublicTicketForm(CustomFieldMixin, forms.Form):
    queue = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Queue.objects.filter(...))
```